# How to indicate the office I'll be working from in MS Outlook?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, calendar

I usually work from our main office location, but I also work from on of our satellite offices on a semi-regular basis (about one day each week). On my Outlook calendar, I want to indicate which days I will be working from the satellite office so that meeting organizers can take that into account. If it matters, I share the full details of calendar, so other people can see the details of any events when they look at my calendar.

I know of three options, but I'm wondering if there is a better way:

1. Not do anything, and then reply to meeting invites for those days with my availability. If I do this, my shared calendar is not fulfilling its real purpose since it doesn't give meeting organizers a true sense of my availability.
2. Mark the days that I know I will be in the satellite office as "Out of Office", but in the event title state that I'll be at the satellite office. This might cause meeting organizers to skip over those days because they'll see the purple Out of Office status in the calendar view, and not realize that I can call in to a meeting at the main office or physically attend meetings at the satellite office.
3. Create an event that has the availability set to Free and add a title that says I'll be at the satellite office. Right now, this seems like the best option, but I've only ever seen people do option 1 or 2, so I'm wondering if I'm missing a disadvantage (or a 4th option that is better).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to advise others that you will be unable to make face-to-face meetings at certain locations on certain days, you can't use "free time" as it won't conflict with the scheduler's proposal.

You also can't rely on the scheduling conflict to alert the scheduler of what your event's title is, so you'd be hard-pressed to make sure they understood the conflict was "I can call in".

I'd just leave it and if someone invites you to something you can't make and don't provide a call-in number, you can reply "tentative" asking for a conference line.

Comment: I'm still going to put an all-day event on my calendar for my own purposes, but unfortunately it doesn't appear in the Scheduling Assistant so meeting organizers won't see it.